# Using Java Code from Android Studio Project In Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am creating an application In Xamarin Studio, and I have an Java Library/ Android studio project for a fingerprint scanner - onyx SDK. which can be found here:

http://www.diamondfortress.com/

Is it possible to incorporate this code into my Xamarin Studio project?

Comment: @shamimreza the C# tag is relevant as that is the coding language for Xamarin.

Comment: You can use Java based Android library/SDK as long as you create appropriate C# bindings. The necessary bindings might already exist, otherwise https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/ will explain the process and help you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to download the onyx SDK and reference it in your Xamarin project.

I dont know why you'd bother when Finger Print scanning is included with Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fingerprint-authentication/

Using the Xamarin one is going to be much better too, as it will be future proof with Xamarin upgrades.

If you want to use the onyx product read the manual and consult their support: http://support.diamondfortress.com/ - when you do find out maybe update the Xamarin forum as well: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49123/fingerprint-authentication-onyx-4-sdk-diamond-fortress

Comment: Based on very limited reading, it looks like the Onyx SDK works differently than Android's built-in fingerprint support. Android's built-in support is only in 6.0+ while the Onyx SDK claims to support 4.0+. I think it's pretty reasonable to want to use that SDK.